# Unable to connect to wifi on 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, 16.04

About a week ago, I upgraded to 16.04 and ever since then, my computer doesn't seem to connect to wifi. I have Windows 10 on another partition, and that connects just fine. LAN connects fine too.

Here's what shows under Network - No Wifi option! When I do `nm-tool`, it says

```
No command 'nm-tool' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dm-tool' from package 'lightdm' (main)
nm-tool: command not found
```

I try tethering from my phone, that doesn't work too. FYI, it worked like a charm before the update!

Please, can you help me?!

Answer (score 0):

Try **nmtui**

nmtui — Text User Interface for controlling NetworkManager

nmtui [edit | connect | hostname] [...] 
nmtui-edit [connection-id | connection-name] 
nmtui-connect [connection-name | connection-uuid | device-name | Wi-Fi-SSID] 
nmtui-hostname

Comment: Ok, what am I supposed to be looking at in this? Anything in particular? The options it gives me are pretty much the same as the regular UI (under System Settings)

Comment: Any help, anyone?